# Product of a modified/generalized geometric progression

Tags: limits, geometric-progressions, pochhammer-symbol

What is the solution to the following? It's sort of a modified/generalized geometric progression (or is there a known name for this kind?),

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=0}^{N}(1+a^n), a\in(0,1)$$

Comment: Try looking at [Q-Pochhammer_symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) for some further inspiration.

Comment: So equation (53) of [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html) has the solution expressed in terms of Jacobi theta function, which I also need some time to understand.